# Need heal with learning HTML::Template in perl

Tags: perl

I would like to learn HTML::Template feature on Perl and the programming language Perl too.
Could some one suggest a good book to me? I was able to get "Perl for Dummies" but one thing it doesn't have HTML::Templates.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any books that discuss HTML::Template.  I suggest that Template Toolkit might be a better choice, and there's even a book specifically about it.

http://template-toolkit.org/

Answer (score 2):

I'd try some tutorials rather than a book, here's a couple of pretty decent ones at a glance:

Good Explanation: http://html-template.sourceforge.net/article.html

Lots of examples: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=65642

And as Jonah Bishop said, this isn't a great question for SO as there is no definitive answer. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

The HTML::Template [CPAN docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Template/lib/HTML/Template.pm) and [CPAN FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/~wonko/HTML-Template/lib/HTML/Template/FAQ.pm) have it pretty much covered, along with  the tutorials mentioned in other answers here.

But none of this will make much sense until you have learnt the basics of Perl - check the O'Reilly books. Also [*Modern Perl*](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html), available as a paper book or (free) pdf download.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for both OReilly and CSPAN. They have lots of books...

Answer (score 0):

Note that this question probably isn't a good fit for SO. That said, I don't know of any books off the top of my head that include `HTML::Template` discussions; you'll have to refer to the module documentation.

The *Learning Perl* book (one of the O'Reilly series) is a fantastic way to learn Perl. It was actually the textbook we used in the Perl class I took back in my college days. I highly recommend it for an overview of the language.